# Exclude a subdirectory from JSHint in my Gruntfile?

Tags: gruntjs, jshint

I am running JSHint automatically from a Gruntfile, and would like to exclude my vendor scripts, since lots of them fail JSHint.

How can I do this? At the moment I am running JSHint across anything in `/app/scripts/` or any subdirectories.

```
jshint: {
  options: {
    jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
    reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
  },
  all: [
    'Gruntfile.js',
    '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js' 
  ]
},
```

I would like to exclude anything in `/app/scripts/vendor`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Just prefix the path with `!` to tell minimatch that it is an exclusion; note when doing this order is important.

```
jshint: {
  options: {
    jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
    reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
  },
  all: [
    'Gruntfile.js',
    '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
    '!<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/vendor/**',
  ]
},
```

Comment: Also useful for ngmin: `src: ['*.js','!*vendor.js'],`